# What is the time complexity of converitng a Map to Linked list

Tags: java, dictionary, time-complexity

I have a `Map` and I am converting it to a `LinkedList`. For example

```
List<Map.Entry<Long, Long>> list = 
    new LinkedList<Map.Entry<Long, Long>>(unsortMap.entrySet());
```

I need to find out the time complexity of doing above operation.

Comment: I assume you looked at the source code. What is the relevant code? What can you tell us about your findings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity is O(n) where n is the number of entries. Its a loop over the entries with a call of list.add(Entry).

```
for(Entry<Long,Long> e : unsortMap.entrySet()){
    list.add(e);
}
```